# vbscript and windows script host error

Tags: vbscript, windows

i tried to runn a vbscript, and i get this message in the picture. how do i fix it?

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 1):

Run it with `cscript scriptname.vbs`

If you need windows pop-ups, then we may need to see the code around the messages you want to pop-up.

Comment: Wow, that's actually pretty cool that the script was written to check and care about that in the first place. I'm not that nice to myself.